# Tesseract init failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, tesseract

I have encounter an issue while I am using tesseract library. I have successfully compiled **leptonica** *and* **tesseract** libs, with **VS2017**. Now, I have used these libraries into MFC project, where they are compiled without any error. Here is the code:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
if (0 != api.Init(NULL, _T("eng"), tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT))
{
    m_sState.Format(_T("tesseract initialize error"));
    return FALSE;
}
```

nothing complicate, nothing wrong ... but I met 2 problems:

1. Even this code is executed or not, I have massive memory leak.

> Detected memory leaks! Dumping objects -> {65734} normal block at
>   0x014EEB88, 24 bytes long.  Data: <        FXDebug > 10 00 00 00 08 00
>   00 00 46 58 44 65 62 75 67 00  {65733} normal block at 0x014EEB40, 24
>   bytes long.  Data: <        FXDebug > 10 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 46 58 44
>   65 62 75 67 00  {65732} normal block at 0x03880908, 8 bytes long. 
>   Data: <        > 10 BE 96 0F 00 00 00 00  {65731} normal block at
>   0x014EBDA8, 32 bytes long.  Data: <  N   N   N     > A8 BD 4E 01 A8 BD
>   4E 01 A8 BD 4E 01 01 01 CD CD  {65730} normal block at 0x03880A20, 8
>   bytes long.  Data: <        > 04 BE 96 0F 00 00 00 00  {65729} normal
>   block at 0x014EE990, 24 bytes long.

2. Every time when this code is executed, the app is going by "tesseract initialize error" route. I don't understand why ...

I have tried to run this project on VS2017 in Win10 64bit, all libraries and my project are compiled as **Debug** ... if this matter ... can you help me in order to use tesseract to read simple images ?

Last edit:
When I include this code inta a console app:

```
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
if (0 != api.Init(NULL, NULL))
{
    std::cout << "tesseract initialize error\n";
    std::cout << "Last error:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Hello World!
Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made
Error opening data file C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
tesseract initialize error
Last error:3
```

but I have not any "Tesseract-OCR" folder in "Program Files (x86)" ...

Comment: The first issue should be a separate question...

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "massive" memory leak, it might be harmless. Probably `api.Init` allocates memory that is never released because the initialisation fails. To find out why `api.Init` fails, step through the code, this will probably give you valuable hints.

Comment: I type there only few lines of ML, but they are hundreds and hundreds of lines of ML (131 123 lines)

Comment: And I going through Init method step by step, with F11, but I go forever into xstring file, without arrive in the problem place ...

Comment: Don't step into `xstring` only step into `api.Init`

Comment: Tesseract and Leptonica are compiled as Debug Win32, Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), and my MFC app is compiled as Debug x86, Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) ...

Comment: I have arrived into xstring endless debugging when I step into api.Init ...

Comment: Does anyone use tesseract into a MFC project ? If yes, can point me to solve my problem ?